# Uk business Visa checklist mistake

Tags: visas, uk, business-travel

I am being sponsored by my company and they have arranged all the documents for me but by mistake I ticked on an extra column on my checklist and later I realized I didn't provide any documents for that. Are they going to reject my visa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are they going to reject my visa?

This is an opinion based question however no **reasonable** ECO is going to refuse a visa because of a minor immaterial error on a checklist. If the documents you provided are enough to issue the visa, checking off additional unnecessary items without providing them will not doom your application.

### Reference

None, just commonsense and a history of making minor mistakes on previous visa applications.