# UK business Visa application mistake

Tags: visas, uk, business-travel

My company is sending me for a business trip to UK but now after doing all the work of appointment and biometrics I reviewed the soft copy of my application form and I saw that by mistake I put my father's first name in my mother's surname field. I don't how this happened but I think I was in a rush and really had no idea because this is the first time I was supposed to travel. I am so depressed and tensed now and I am 100% sure they'll reject my application on the basis of this mistake. I don't know how I'll tell about this to my employer. Does anyone have any suggestion please?

Comment: [Clerical mistake in UK visa application: should I make a pen-and-ink correction or electronically edit the PDF?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/106893/clerical-mistake-in-uk-visa-application-should-i-make-a-pen-and-ink-correction) This is a classic case of post submission anxiety. It is not a material error and your application is unlikely to be refused solely because of that. 

If everything has already been submitted, just wait for the results of your application.

Comment: Also stop asking essentially the same question in different forms like you did here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138978/uk-business-visa-checklist-mistake

Comment: Thank you so much user 56513, your answers to my questions have really ease my mind. Also, I apologize for asking duplicate questions on this forum as I am a little distressed. I'll try not to bother anymore.